# MFP 7 and IBM App centre compatibility with Blackberry 10

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

As we are in process of upgrading our Worklight platform from 6.2 to MFP7 I couldn't find if MFP7 will support BB10 certification.

The features we are interested in:

1. Direct Update on BB10 (As we are doing monthly release we have to
   submit to BB app store every time), Will this feature be available
   on MFP or in the near future?
2. IBM App centre only support BB6/7. Will IBM App centre support
   BB10 so we can deploy the binary (.bar)in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The BlackBerry 10 environment does not support Direct Update.

Application Center [does not support](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/moving-production/distributing-mobile-applications-with-application-center/) BlackBerry 10 (there is no AppCenter client for it)